# sqlplus command failing inside shell script while calling that scripts from remote machine

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, sqlplus

I am facing very strange problem while, triggering shell scripts from remote machine. the issue is that the local shell scripts have database call using sqlplus client, and it was working fine. but the same script i run from remote machine, the script execution is failing and throwing some error related to *.so file (error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory). so can u suggest me what would be possible cause? (does this means sqlplus is required to remote machine as well?)

Thanks in advance,
Priyank Shah

Answer (score 0):

The oracle runtime is required on the remote machine as well.  It may just be a matter of setting up environment variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH, because sqlplus seems to be on the remote machine - based on your question.

Try this command on the remote machine:

```
ldd `which sqlplus`
```

When sqlplus is installed but LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not point to the Oracle runtime libraries, you will see something like 'not found'  next to  dynamically linked libraries in ldd output.

Comment: i tried this command from from remote machines and it seems sqlclient is not installed in remote machine.. so in such situation we can not make db call right please correct me if i am wrong?